# Vue Router duplicate $route info

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I have a route and sub route like these.

```
export default new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/user',
      component: UserView,
      meta: {title: 'User Manager'},
      children: [
        {path: 'editor', component: EditorView, meta: {title: 'User Editor'}}
      ]
    }
  ]
})
```

In `UserView` and `EditorView` both have mounted function.

```
export defaults {
  mounted () {
    console.log(this.$route)
  }
}
```

And i type `http://host:port/#/user/editor` in browser, the console print twice `$route` data and they is same object. How could i get `UserView` route data?

```
{name: undefined, meta: {…}, path: "/user/editor", hash: "", query: {…}, …}
{name: undefined, meta: {…}, path: "/user/editor", hash: "", query: {…}, …}
```

[image]

`UserView` and `EditorView` is in the same page and they html look like this picture.
[image]

Comment: Did you route change or are both of the components on the same page? The route changes based on the URI, not the component loaded.

Comment: @JimWright They are on the same page, i have updated question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple route parts that are matched for a given URL when nested routes are involved. You'll need to search `this.$route.matched` for the specific route that you are interested in.

If you set a name for the route you're interested in, it'll make it easier to find:

```js
{
  path: 'editor',
  name: 'editor',  // <-- Add this
  component: EditorView,
  meta: {
    title: 'User Editor'
  }
}
```

```js
mounted() {
  const route = this.$route.matched.find(r => r.name === 'editor');
  console.log(route.meta.title);
}
```

Comment: `matched` is the same, i have updated my question. If i type `http://host:port/#/user` and then go to `#/user/editor`, it work fine. The problem is that i go `#/user/editor` at first.

Comment: I'm not sure specifically what your problem is. `$route` (and hence `$route.matched`) will be the same for all components. `$route` does not represent the matched route for that particular component.